# Is new server request sent every time when url clicked/accessed/pressed?

Tags: http, webserver

For example in address bar if I press enter to load url and than close the tab while it's starting to load? Is request sent anyway in this case?

If yes, also i would be interested in a bit more details about what is sent and what not, or what is sent back?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** the request is sent every time. When you click a link or access a page the request is sent and then the browser waits until the response comes back from the server.

See this article for more in depth details http://devhub.fm/http-requestresponse-basics.

Comment: thanks this is useful, I will check

Comment: This answer is wrong. Scripts can interact here, not doing a request each time. Also the browser can refuse to request if something is in cache. The right answer is to point to the product documentation of the browser because this can depend on many things that are only documented with the browser.